# installing sphinx on mac OS X version 10.8.2 and configuring

Tags: sphinx

can anyone pls tell me how to install sphinx on mac OS X version 10.8.2

Now, How can I check whether its properly installed or mot??

where can i find the files i installed

getting error while trying to run `./configure` command got this error

```
unknown-5c:96:9d:7d:44:c7:sphinx-2.0.1-beta username$ ./configure

checking build environment
--------------------------

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no

checking for compiler programs
------------------------------

checking whether to compile debug version... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/username/Downloads/sphinx-2.0.1-beta':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

how can resolve this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely

> configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Is pretty clear...?

https://www.google.com/search?q=install+c+compiler+mac+os